# Creditmemo Grand Total does not include Tax

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, creditmemo

I recently updated my Payment Module (MultiSafePay) to version 2.2.1 and this creates a weird error which causes my credit memos to be wrong.
Source: https://www.multisafepay.com/nl_nl/oplossingen/shop-plug-ins/detail/plugins/magento/

The grand total of my credit memos do not include the tax. But the tax is being shown correctly. Thus the subtotal is actually the actual subtotal minus the tax.

To show what I mean, I'll include some print screens of a example order with a total value of 174.20 euros, the subtotal is 151.78 and the tax is 22.42.

Creating an order and invoice goes like a charm.

1. I create the order, values seem correct
   [image: Creating the order]
2. Order is created, looks as expected
   [image: Order is created]
3. I create the invoice, again the numbers seem correct
   [image: Creation of the invoice]
4. Jup that invoice looks great1
   [image: Invoice created]
5. Now here is where it gets weird, at first the credit memo I am about to create shows all the correct values!
   [image: Products in the credit memo]
   [image: Creation of the credit memo, all looks normal]
6. But when the credit memo is created, the total is wrong, it is the subtotal without the tax, however the tax is mentioned on the form.
   [image: Wrong credit memo]

Normally the grand total is 174.2, but now the grand total suddenly ends up being 174.2 - 22.42 (the tax) = 151.78.

The only solution to this problem is to manually go into the database and manipulate the records in the sales_flat_creditmemo and sales_flat_creditmemo_grid table and manually set the grand_total and base_grand_total to the correct 174.20 value, which is the wrong 151.78 after generation of the credit memo.

Which is a lot of unnecessary work.

My current tax settings are the following:
[image: Tax settings]
[image: Tax settings]

The credit memo record in the database:
[image: Credit memo record in DB]

But I don't see how this could have any effect on the problem.

A downgrade isn't much of an option since it had other issues like double invoices and double payment request mails to our customers etc (credit memos worked fine though) and we like to use the new features in the new version.

The module developers are looking into the problem but can't recreate it so I am not sure if it is caused by the module. Is this a known issue in Magento? This bug is costing us a bunch of time and I can't seem to find anything wrong in the module code so I'm basically just bashing my head on the table here. All help or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in the 2.2.1 version of the MSP module. MSP is aware of this issue and have an updated version which you can get through their support